# How to navigate "in one direction" using navigation component?

Tags: android, xml

Image i have login fragment. I want to enter login and password. After that i want to navigate to "main screen" and pop up login fragment but we can't just use `popUpTo` because main screen doesn't exist before we are navigating to it. So how can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `popUpTo`:

```
       <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_mainFragment"
            app:destination="@id/mainFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```

Comment: How is this works? We are heading from login to main, but we popUpTo login and popping it off of backstack? :/

Comment: Yes, it clears the stack before login (nothing in your case) and removes login fragment.

Comment: This works strange to be honest